# JQuery: Make pop up window appear right under the button that's being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

does anyone know a simple solution for making a pop-up window appear right below the button being clicked, no matter what the screen size?

This is my current code, the button being clicked is variable "help":

```
  $help = $('.help'); 

  var position = $help.position();

  $help.click(function() {
      var x =position.left;
      var y = position.top;
      var helpWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100, left=" + x + ",top=" + y);
      helpWindow.document.write("<p>Info text</p>");

    });
```

This is close, but doesn't go right under the button. I'm wondering if there is a better solution to do this. Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work

```js
// help popout
$('.help, .popOut .close a').click(function() {
  $('.pop').toggleClass('popOut');
});
```

```css
.help {
    float: left;
}

.help a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    background-color: #3377DD;
}

.help a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pop {
    display: none;
}

.popOut {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.popOut p {
    color: #242424;
}

.close a {
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #F0F0F0;
    background-color: #A10000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
}

.content {
    float: left;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="help">
 <p><a>Help</a></p>
 <div class="pop">
  <div class="close"><a>X</a></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>     
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, apart from one problem - it causes other elements in the form to move according to the size of  the box. Do you know of a good way to make it just an overlay or prevent the rest of the elements to be responsive in this way?

Comment: Nevermind, managed to fix it by using position:fixed and z-index: 100 :)

Comment: @feiti I edited the snippet to show an absolute positioning option in case you don't want the div fixed.

Comment: @feiti here is a couple of different options if desired.  Both will close your pop out div when clicked away from it. - https://jsfiddle.net/iMarketingGuy/8e19g3f4/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.help').click( function(event) {
  $("#modal").css( {display:"block",position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
}); });
```

```css
#modal{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:none;
}

.help{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modal" >Helper window</div>
<div class="help" > Click inside the div !!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use window.open I suggest you to use the classical [jQuery dialog widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).
In order to load some html document inside the dialog you may use [jQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function to replace the text inside the dialog.

```js
    $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $(':button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        });

        $('#myBtn').on('click', function(e){
            if ($('#dialog').is(':visible') == false) {
                $.get('??? YOUR LOCAL URL ???', function(data) {
                    $('#dialogContent').empty().append(data);
                    var myPos = 'left+' + (e.pageX+10) + ' top+' + (e.pageY+10);
                    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'position', {my: 'left top', at: myPos, of: window}).dialog('open');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
   <div id="dialogContent"></div>
</div>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you wanna use a regular browser window. In that case, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#example').on('click', function(){
    var $w = $(window);
    var $example = $('#example');

    var clientWidth = $w.width();
    var windowChromeWidth = window.outerWidth - clientWidth;
    var windowScrollLeft = $w.scrollLeft();
    var elementLeftPositionInViewport = $example.scrollLeft() - windowScrollLeft;
    var screenX = window.screenX;
    var newWindowX = screenX + windowChromeWidth + elementLeftPositionInViewport;

    var clientHeight = $w.height();
    var windowChromeHeight = window.outerHeight - clientHeight;
    var windowScrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var elementTopPositionInViewport = $example.scrollTop() - windowScrollTop;
    var screenY = window.screenY;
    var elementHeight = $example.height();
    var newWindowY = screenY + windowChromeHeight + elementTopPositionInViewport + elementHeight;

    var helpWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100, left=" + newWindowX + ",top=" + newWindowY);
  });
});
```

Here's the live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sirarthurnell/wqff8qLL/2/).